# Why does my Regional Proposal Network (RPN) output 4d array of predictions / scores and how do I interpret output?

Tags: python, keras, object-detection

## Introduction

I would like to create a Region Proposal Network (RPN) using VGG16 and Kera (Python) framework. I am struggling to understand how to interpret the output of the RPN to predict bounding boxes of foreground objects.

**Why does the RPN produce an array with 5x5 times the number of anchor boxes and how do I know which element corresponds to an anchor box?**

```
    # Below is some lovely pseudo-code
    array_of_feature_maps = topless_vgg_model.predict(pre_processed_img)
    print(array_of_feature_maps.shape)
    >>> (1,7,7,52)

    all_anchor_boxes = get_potential_boxes_for_region_proposal()
    print(len(all_anchor_boxes))
    >>> 784

    predicted_scores_for_anchor_boxes, predicted_adjustments = rpn_model.predict(input_feature_map)
    # 4 * 784 = 3136
    print(f"Scores Shape = {predicted_scores_for_anchor_boxes.shape}, Adjustments (Deltas) Shape = {predicted_adjustments.shape}")
    >>> Scores Shape = (1,5,5,784), Adjustments (Deltas) Shape = (1,5,5,3136)
```

Have I made a mistake when creating the RPN? Can I just chose element [0][0][0] and get the scores / deltas? My main resources which I am following are these

- https://dongjk.github.io/code/object+detection/keras/2018/05/21/Faster_R-CNN_step_by_step,_Part_I.html
- https://dongjk.github.io/code/object+detection/keras/2018/06/10/Faster_R-CNN_step_by_step,_Part_II.html

## Here is the nitty gritty code

The main function is at the top under the config dictionary.

```
    from keras import Model
    from keras import models
    from keras import optimizers
    from keras import Sequential
    from keras import layers
    from keras import losses
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    from keras.optimizers import Adam
    import keras.backend as K
    import keras.applications
    from keras import applications
    from keras import utils
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import os
    import math
    
    config = {
        "ImgPath" : "1. Data Gen\\1. Data\\1X9A1712.jpg" #"Put your image path here"
        ,"VGG16InputSize" : (224,224)
        ,"AnchorBox" : {
            "AspectRatioW_div_W" : [1/3,1/2,3/4,1]
            ,"Scales" : [1/2,3/4,1,3/2]
        }
    }

    def main(): ############ MAIN FUNCTION - START HERE ############
        # Get vgg model
        vggmodel = applications.VGG16(include_top=False,weights='imagenet') 
    
        # Extract features for images (used dictionary comprehension to stop getting warning messages from Keras)
        list_of_images = [cv2.imread(config["ImgPath"])]
        array_of_prediction_ready_images = pre_process_image_for_vgg(list_of_images)
        array_of_feature_maps = vggmodel.predict(array_of_prediction_ready_images)
    
        # Find conversions from feature map (CNN output) to input image
        feature_to_input_x_scale, feature_to_input_y_scale, feature_to_input_x_offset, feature_to_input_y_offset = find_feature_map_to_input_scale_and_offset(array_of_prediction_ready_images[0],array_of_feature_maps[0])
    
        # get potential boxes, aka anchor boxes
        potential_boxes = get_potential_boxes_for_region_proposal(array_of_prediction_ready_images[0],array_of_feature_maps[0],feature_to_input_x_scale, feature_to_input_y_scale, feature_to_input_x_offset, feature_to_input_y_offset)
    
        # Create region proposal network
        rpn_model = create_region_proposal_network(len(potential_boxes))
    
        # Output following (height, width, anchor_num)     (height, width, anchor_num * 4)
        predicted_scores_for_anchor_boxes, predicted_adjustments  = rpn_model.predict(array_of_feature_maps)
    
        print(f"predicted_scores_for_anchor_boxes.shape = {predicted_scores_for_anchor_boxes.shape}, predicted_adjustments.shape = {predicted_adjustments.shape}")
        print(f"But why is there the ,5,5, bit? I don't know which ones to choose now to get the predicted bounding box?")
    def pre_process_image_for_vgg(img):
        """
            Resizes the image to input of VGGInputSize specified in the config dictionary
            Normalises the image
            Reshapes the image to an array of images e.g. [[img],[img],..]
    
            If img has a shape of
        """
        if type(img) == np.ndarray: # Single image 
            resized_img = cv2.resize(img,config["VGG16InputSize"],interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            normalised_image = applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(resized_img)
            reshaped_to_array_of_images = np.array([normalised_image])
            return reshaped_to_array_of_images
        elif type(img) == list: # list of images
            img_list = img
            resized_img_list = [cv2.resize(image,config["VGG16InputSize"],interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA) for image in img_list]
            resized_img_array = np.array(resized_img_list)
            normalised_images_array = applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(resized_img_array)
            return normalised_images_array
    
    def find_feature_map_to_input_scale_and_offset(pre_processed_input_image,feature_maps):
        """
            Finds the scale and offset from the feature map (output) of the CNN classifier to the pre-processed input image of the CNN
        """
        # Find shapes of feature maps and input images to the classifier CNN
        input_image_shape = pre_processed_input_image.shape
        feature_map_shape = feature_maps.shape
        img_height, img_width, _ = input_image_shape
        features_height, features_width, _ = feature_map_shape
    
        # Find mapping from features map (output of vggmodel.predict) back to the input image
        feature_to_input_x = img_width / features_width
        feature_to_input_y = img_height / features_height
    
        # Put anchor points in the centre of 
        feature_to_input_x_offset = feature_to_input_x/2
        feature_to_input_y_offset = feature_to_input_y/2
    
        return feature_to_input_x, feature_to_input_y, feature_to_input_x_offset, feature_to_input_y_offset
    
    def get_get_coordinates_of_anchor_points(feature_map,feature_to_input_x,feature_to_input_y,x_offset,y_offset):
        """
            Maps the CNN output (Feature map) coordinates on the input image to the CNN 
            Returns the coordinates as a list of dictionaries with the format {"x":x,"y":y}
        """
        features_height, features_width, _ = feature_map.shape
    
        # For the feature map (x,y) determine the anchors on the input image (x,y) as array 
        feature_to_input_coords_x  = [int(x_feature*feature_to_input_x+x_offset) for x_feature in range(features_width)]
        feature_to_input_coords_y  = [int(y_feature*feature_to_input_y+y_offset) for y_feature in range(features_height)]
        coordinate_of_anchor_points = [{"x":x,"y":y} for x in feature_to_input_coords_x for y in feature_to_input_coords_y]
    
        return coordinate_of_anchor_points
    
    def get_potential_boxes_for_region_proposal(pre_processed_input_image,feature_maps,feature_to_input_x, feature_to_input_y, x_offset, y_offset):
        """
            Generates the anchor points (the centre of the enlarged feature map) as an (x,y) position on the input image
            Generates all the potential bounding boxes for each anchor point
            returns a list of potential bounding boxes in the form {"x1","y1","x2","y2"}
        """
        # Find shapes of input images to the classifier CNN
        input_image_shape = pre_processed_input_image.shape
    
        # For the feature map (x,y) determine the anchors on the input image (x,y) as array 
        coordinate_of_anchor_boxes = get_get_coordinates_of_anchor_points(feature_maps,feature_to_input_x,feature_to_input_y,x_offset,y_offset)
    
        # Create potential boxes for classification
        boxes_width_height = generate_potential_box_dimensions(config["AnchorBox"],feature_to_input_x,feature_to_input_y)
        list_of_potential_boxes_for_coords = [generate_potential_boxes_for_coord(boxes_width_height,coord) for coord in coordinate_of_anchor_boxes]
        potential_boxes = [box for boxes_for_coord in list_of_potential_boxes_for_coords for box in boxes_for_coord]
        
        return potential_boxes
    
    def generate_potential_box_dimensions(settings,feature_to_input_x,feature_to_input_y):
        """
            Generate potential boxes height & width for each point aka anchor boxes given the 
            ratio between feature map to input scaling for x and y
            Assumption 1: Settings will have the following attributes
                AspectRatioW_div_W: A list of float values representing the aspect ratios of
                    the anchor boxes at each location on the feature map
                Scales: A list of float values representing the scale of the anchor boxes
                    at each location on the feature map.
        """
        box_width_height = []
        for scale in settings["Scales"]:
            for aspect_ratio_w_div_h in settings["AspectRatioW_div_W"]:
                width = round(feature_to_input_x*scale*aspect_ratio_w_div_h)
                height = round(feature_to_input_y*scale/aspect_ratio_w_div_h)
                box_width_height.append({"Width":width,"Height":height})
        return box_width_height
    
    def generate_potential_boxes_for_coord(box_width_height,coord):
        """
            Assumption 1: box_width_height is an array of dictionary with each dictionary consisting of
                {"Width":positive integer, "Height": positive integer}
            Assumption 2: coord is an array of dictionary with each dictionary consistening of
                {"x":centre of box x coordinate,"y",centre of box y coordinate"}
        """
        potential_boxes = []
        for box_dim in box_width_height:
            potential_boxes.append({
                "x1": coord["x"]-int(box_dim["Width"]/2)
                ,"y1": coord["y"]-int(box_dim["Height"]/2)
                ,"x2": coord["x"]+int(box_dim["Width"]/2)
                ,"y2": coord["y"]+int(box_dim["Height"]/2)
            })
        return potential_boxes
    
    def create_region_proposal_network(number_of_potential_bounding_boxes,number_of_feature_map_channels=512):
        """
            Creates the region proposal network which takes the input of the feature map and 
            Compiles the model and returns it
    
            RPN consists of an input later, a CNN and two output layers.
                output_deltas: 
                output_scores:
    
            Note: Number of feature map channels should be the last element of model.predict().shape
        """
        # Input layer
        feature_map_tile = layers.Input(shape=(None,None,number_of_feature_map_channels),name="RPN_Input_Same")
        # CNN component
        convolution_3x3 = layers.Conv2D(filters=512,kernel_size=(3, 3),name="3x3")(feature_map_tile)
        # Output layers
        output_deltas = layers.Conv2D(filters= 4 * number_of_potential_bounding_boxes,kernel_size=(1, 1),activation="linear",kernel_initializer="uniform",name="Output_Deltas")(convolution_3x3)
        output_scores = layers.Conv2D(filters=1 * number_of_potential_bounding_boxes,kernel_size=(1, 1),activation="sigmoid",kernel_initializer="uniform",name="Output_Prob_FG")(convolution_3x3)
    
        model = Model(inputs=[feature_map_tile], outputs=[output_scores, output_deltas])
    
        # TODO add loss_cls and smoothL1
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'scores1':losses.binary_crossentropy, 'deltas1':losses.huber})
    
        return model
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

## My Research So Far

1. [Step by step explanation of RPN + extra] - https://dongjk.github.io/code/object+detection/keras/2018/05/21/Faster_R-CNN_step_by_step,_Part_I.html
2. [vgg with top=false will only output the feature maps which is (7,7,512), other solutions will have different features produced] - https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4465
3. [Understanding anchor boxes] - https://machinelearningmastery.com/padding-and-stride-for-convolutional-neural-networks/
4. [Faster RCNN - how they calculate stride] - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314823/how-is-the-stride-calculated-in-the-faster-rcnn-paper
5. [Good article on Faster RCNN explained] - https://medium.com/@smallfishbigsea/faster-r-cnn-explained-864d4fb7e3f8
6. [Indicating that Anchor boxes should be determine by ratio and scale ratio should be width:height of 1:2 1:1 2:1 scale should be 1 1/2 1/3] - https://keras.io/examples/vision/retinanet/
7. [Best explanation of anchor boxes] - [https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/anchor-boxes-for-object-detection.html#:~:text=Anchor%20boxes%20are%20a%20set,sizes%20in%20your%20training%20datasets](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/anchor-boxes-for-object-detection.html#:%7E:text=Anchor%20boxes%20are%20a%20set,sizes%20in%20your%20training%20datasets)
8. [Summary of object detection history, interesting read] - https://dudeperf3ct.github.io/object/detection/2019/01/07/Mystery-of-Object-Detection/
9. [Mask RCNN Jupyter Notebook] - https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/samples/coco/inspect_model.ipynb
10. [RPN in Python Keras which i'm trying to understand] - https://github.com/dongjk/faster_rcnn_keras/blob/master/RPN.py
11. [RPN implementation Keras Python] - https://github.com/you359/Keras-FasterRCNN/blob/master/keras_frcnn/data_generators.py
12. [RPN implementation Well Commented] - https://github.com/virgil81188/Region-Proposal-Network/tree/03025cde75c1d634b608c277e6aa40ccdb829693
13. [RPN Loss function clearly explained] - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/faster-r-cnn-ml/
14. [RPN Developed in Keras Python Framework] - https://github.com/alexmagsam/keras-rpn

wow you made it all the way to the bottom, hope you had a good read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confusing anchor boxes and anchor points.

- Anchor Points: Relates to the coordinates on a feature map (output of the backbone classifier)
- Anchor boxes: The scale and aspect ratio of each of the anchor points

This mistake that I was making in the below code that instead of using `number_of_potential_bounding_boxes` which was 784 which is `feature_width*feature_height*scale_boxes*aspect_ratios`. Instead it should be 16 as `scale_boxes*aspect_ratios`

```py
  # Output layers
        output_deltas = layers.Conv2D(filters= 4 * number_of_potential_bounding_boxes,kernel_size=(1, 1),activation="linear",kernel_initializer="uniform",name="Output_Deltas")(convolution_3x3)
        output_scores = layers.Conv2D(filters=1 * number_of_potential_bounding_boxes,kernel_size=(1, 1),activation="sigmoid",kernel_initializer="uniform",name="Output_Prob_FG")(convolution_3x3)
```

So the output should be `[:,7,7,16]`

Which is the following

```py
[number of images to be predicted, height of feature map, width of feature map, number of anchor boxes per anchor point scales*aspect ratios]
```

I have implemented two simple RPN without regression below

1. https://github.com/alexshellabear/Simple-Region-Proposal-Network
2. https://github.com/alexshellabear/Still-Simple-Region-Proposal-Network

Answer (score 1):

Keras/Tensorflow use the BHWC convention for Tensor shapes (also called "channel-last"). Looking at the output shape of your VGG model, which is `(1, 7, 7, 52)`, this means that the spatial grid is of size 7x7 and there are 52 channels. The RPN you defined output a tensor of shape `(1, 5, 5, 784)`, which you guessed right has a lower spatial resolution as the VGG network.

From your RPN code, the explanation is simple: you used a `Conv2D` with a kernel size of 3x3 and default value for padding, which is 'valid'. This means that the output spatial extend will be smaller than the input one because the convolution only occurs at "valid" locations, i.e where the kernel fits inside the input tensor.

`padding='same'` will solve this issue and you'll have a tensor of shape `(1, 7, 7, 784)`.

The formula to to compute the output tensor shape wrt the input tensor shape and convolution parameter is given by (channel-first, its is PyTorch documentation):

[image]

where `padding`, `dilation`, `kernel_size` and `stride` are tuples of `(int, int)` corresponding to values for the height dimension and the width one.

Comment: Hi Louis, thanks so much for taking the time to answer this question in such detai;.
Great point on using padding='same'
Now that I have a (1,7,7,784) output for the scores, how would I map that back to the anchor boxes? 

Lets say all_anchor_boxes[0] had the foreground, how would I get that information from the output? Would it be predicted_scores_for_anchor_boxes[0][0][0][0] be equal to 1 indicating foreground?

Comment: As in the tutorial you liked, the first `4 * number_of_potential_bounding_boxes` channels are the anchor bounding boxes and the last `number_of_potential_bounding_boxes` are the scores (foreground vs background). Read again the literature on anchor boxes to figure out how to extract them from this tensor.

Comment: For instance to get all the scores of the output tensor `t` of shape `(1, 7, 7, 784)` you can do: `t[..., 4 * number_of_potential_bounding_boxes:]`, you'll end up with a tensor of shape `(1, 7, 7, number_of_potential_bounding_boxes)` of all scores.